# Clipping with gdal translate does not create a file (Python)

Tags: python, gdal, clip, gdal-translate

I have tried to clip a geotiff file using the code below:

```
from osgeo import gdal

miny=-10.616665787
maxy=38.558338147
minx=34.562256098
maxx=71.187259028


ds = gdal.Open(fp)
ds = gdal.Translate(out_tif, ds, projWin =  [maxx, miny, minx, maxy])
ds = None
```

For some reason no file is generated though, when I tried using different coordinates it worked perfectly:

```
from osgeo import gdal

ds = gdal.Open('original.tif')
ds = gdal.Translate('new.tif', ds, projWin = [-75.3, 5.5, -73.5, 3.7])
ds = None
```

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be? This is the area I am working with:
 [image: This is the area I Am working with]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
ds = gdal.Translate('new.tif', ds, projWin = [-73.5, 3.7, -75.3, 5.5])
```

I believe your max min are inverted.

Comment: It worked for me using this format: [miny, maxx, maxy, minx]